# Spring JpaRepository doesn't update table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have next JPARepo code:

```
public interface MyObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObject, UUID> {
  @Modifying
  @Query("UPDATE MyObject obj SET obj.deleted = true WHERE obj.objectId = ?1")
  void deleteById(UUID uuid);
}
```

and Service for it's calling:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MyService {
@Autowired
  private MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository;

  // some methods here

  @Transactional
  public void deleteMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
    ** first way **
    myRepository.deleteById(myObject.getMyObjectId());
    ** second way **
    myObject.setDeleted(true);
    myObjectRepository.save(myObject);
  }

  //some methods here

}
```

two ways of updating are executed only once. The next time I call method, entity's value at delete column is false by default and after update it stays false. But when in debug I look at the table step by step, I see that deleted column was set to true and when I release debug, delete flag is set to false again. 
Is it caching or incorrect annotating?

Comment: Maybe some exception is thrown and a roolback occurs

Comment: @RC. Nope, everything's clear

Comment: Executing an update query isn't directly reflected in your object model. You would have to forcefully reload the object from the database after the execution of the specific update query. (You are modifying the object state outside the scope if hibernate). So as long as that if `false` that will be the case for your application. If you ow update different things (or otherwise trigger query) the state will be reset because the in-memory and db state differ).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your comment. I've tried to change readonly to falsem but no result. Or did u mean other case ?

Comment: Is the table actually phisically updated on the db? Also to be sure, it is not updated for both of the methods?

Comment: Have you read the comment? I mention nowhere the readonly status or transactionality of the method... I question your ways of updating the object.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski as I've mentioned in the question - if I watch table in debug mode step-by-step, I see how column is set to true, then to false

Comment: @M.Deinum I just didn't get your comment, could you please clarify?

Comment: You are updating things in the database directly and with that you are bypassing hibernate. Hibernate still has the object value at the previous value (that isn't updating due to you updating things directly with a query).

Comment: and how should I fix/handle that?

Answer (score 1):

I think `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` at the class level applies to all methods, Can you change it to `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` in the method level.

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public void deleteMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
```

Comment: actually it is written in `MyService` - method is `Transactional` (by default it is false), also I've tried to set it on class level as `readonly = false`, but no result

Comment: Have you tried in the method level... Anyways it should work when you put in class level

Comment: In your second way , I think entity would be detached. Try to find the entity and then set property

Comment: I made DB call at higher level, at controller

Comment: I think sometimes if you still pass the entity from other layer and do the transaction in service layer that may work wierd.. I am not sure

Comment: Tried to fetch data in the same method where I call delete - same problem =(

Comment: Are you using jsp's?.. are you doing page refresh?

Comment: fetching won't help as you will get the object from the first level cache NOT from the database. You will have to clear the first level cache to force an read from the database again.